# Updating a table from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, draggable

I'm working on the following webpage and have reached a problem. Here's what happens on the site: On, the "mouseup" event after dragging a row, the following events occurs.

1. server updates the "order number" in the database
2. server returns the updated database back to the browser.
3. browser displays the update info.

The problem is that when the browser is updated, the rows are not draggable any more. 
When modifying a table dynamically through Javascript, do I need to reload the Javascript "include files" again or something?  If you need source code, I can provide.

here is the site
(link now removed, the problem solved)

Currently, I have it simply adding a new row with "made up" information every time you drag something **only for testing purposes**. What I would like to know, is how to make those new added rows draggable like the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Those new rows are being added to the table but never attached by the javascript library that is allowing you to drag and drop. Also, there seems to be some issue where I'm getting a repeat row? A lot of "Earthquake in Haiti"'s.

Check out the site for the plugin you're using to see how to add new rows into its control.

From the tableDnD website:

```
Added $(‘…’).tableDnDUpdate() to cause the table to update its rows so the drag and drop functionality works if, for example, you’ve added a row.
```

So call that function when the rows are inserted/updated.

Comment: yea. i have it that way for testing only. once i get the row to become draggable, then i'll change that. So you say that i havent attached the new rows to the drag/drop library?

Comment: thanks. ok. i'll do that right now. I guess i incorrectly added them :/

Comment: "Added $(‘…’).tableDnDUpdate() to cause the table to update its rows so the drag and drop functionality works if, for example, you’ve added a row." - from their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery, which I notice has a Drag and Drop plugin, whose comment section had the following that may be helpful:

@Ian Q: I had a similar problem, when DnD didn’t worked for rows added after initialization.

var params = {
onDragClass: “onDragRow”,
onDrop: function(table, row) { },
onDragStart: function(table, row) {}
};
// Initialization
$(“table”).tableDnD(params);

Then call $(“table”).tableDnD(params); everytime you add rows to that table.

Comment: Any word resolving your issue? I'm curious about this as well, because I might be working this into the app in the near future.

Comment: i ended up using a javascript library that does all the messy stuff. (late reply i know..)

Comment: I ended up working for another company, which is ALSO a solution, technically :)